# ERROR logged java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index when reading an Excel file using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

When reading an external Excel (.xlsx) file from the UK Government (see https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5d8b3abded915d0373d3540f/File_1_-_IMD2019_Index_of_Multiple_Deprivation.xlsx), an exception is not thrown, but an ERROR is logged:

```
09:13:35.150 [nREPL-session-b3e5d112-80a2-45f3-9e26-095934eeb06a] ERROR org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection - Cannot convert All%20of%20the%20data%20files%20and%20supporting%20documents%20for%20the%20English%20Indices%20of%20Deprivation%202019%20are%20available%20from:%20www.gov.uk/government/statistics/english-indices-of-deprivation-2019 in a valid relationship URI-> dummy-URI used
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 3: All%20of%20the%20data%20files%20and%20supporting%20documents%20for%20the%20English%20Indices%20of%20Deprivation%202019%20are%20available%20from:%20www.gov.uk/government/statistics/english-indices-of-deprivation-2019
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2976) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3147) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3173) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagingURIHelper.toURI(PackagingURIHelper.java:723) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:358) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:160) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:130) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:565) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:751) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:322) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:97) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224) ~[poi-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329) [poi-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224) [poi-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185) [poi-5.2.3.jar:5.2.3]
```

I presume the source file has an error in it, or part of the content is misclassified as a URI and then java.net.URI fails to parse it. I can proceed to read the file contents using POI without difficulty despite the error being logged. I could suppress the error by changing the logging level but is there another way of preventing this error being logged?

Here is a log4j2 configuration that suppresses error logging for this error, but this seems to be a quite dramatic step for what appears to not be an exceptional condition in an otherwise fine xlsx file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <!-- Turn off ERROR logging from the internals of POI when a URI cannot be parsed -->
        <Logger name="org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection" level="off">
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Axel. That explains it but I am surprised to see a log error from a library like this when as the client of that library, I am able to decide whether I’m concerned about errors such as this - having it logged seems surprising behaviour and I wondered whether it was possible to configure how errors are handled such that as the consumer of the library, I can decide what to do about it. Perhaps it’s not possible except by changing the log level. I couldn’t find anything else in the docs and hence my question on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I download the file and open it in Excel, the whole text box on first sheet "Notes" has a hyperlink set. But that link is broken and even Excel cannot follow it. Thus also Apache POI can not follow it. That's why the error.

One can check that by mouse hovering over an empty part of the text box. A hand cursor appears and on click Excel tells that it cannot follow the link.

Since all is open source, one can have a look into the sources to follow the program flow.

[PackagingURIHelper.toURI](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackagingURIHelper.java?view=markup#l662):

```java
...
    return new URI(value);
...
```

Here [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-) throws `java.net.URISyntaxException` if the given string `value` violates RFC 2396, as augmented by the deviations described in constructor of `java.net.URI`.

The `PackagingURIHelper.toURI` gets called by [PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart in a try-catch-block](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackageRelationshipCollection.java?view=markup#l353)

```java
...
        try {
            // when parsing of the given uri fails, we can either
            // ignore this relationship, which leads to IllegalStateException
            // later on, or use a dummy value and thus enable processing of the
            // package
            target = PackagingURIHelper.toURI(value);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            LOG.atError().withThrowable(e).log("Cannot convert {} in a valid relationship URI-> dummy-URI used", value);
        }
        addRelationship(target, targetMode, type, id);
...
```

Here the comment tells why `URISyntaxException` gets catched an logged. Else it would break the whole parsing-relationship-process while reading the `*.xlsx`. That would be much whorse than the error log entry.

So the behavior is by design. One could think, that the log entry should not be on ERROR level, as it is not critical. But that can only be changed by the Apache POI developers. So please file a bug report or a change request to Apache POI.